# Problema al querer eliminar una fila Hibernate : Dependent foreign key constraint violation in a referential integrity constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, sybase

Tengo el siguiente problema en Sybase cuando necesito realizar un DELETE con Hibernate (HQL) en la entidad Caracteristica, donde el idDTO debe pasa a la Query como parametro a la condicion de LA FK idProduccion. No puedo comprender porque no me hace el DELETE Hibernate y me tira el error que pongo al final.

Controlller:

```
@Transactional
public void removeCaracteristica (@RequestBody DTO dto){ 
            
            Long idDto = dto.getId();
    
            try {

                //Delete Caracteristica
                caracteristicaRepository.deleteById(idDto);

                
                                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.message;
            }
```

Query/Repository:

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Caracteristica c "
            + "WHERE c.produccion.id = :idDto"
        
        )
    
    
    public void deleteById (@Param("idDto")Long idDto);
```

Entidad Caracteristica

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "caracteristica")
public class Caracteristica {

    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_produccion", nullable = true)
    Produccion produccion;

//mas metodos getters y setters y atributos
```

Error:

```
2020-12-30 15:57:59.892 ERROR 6944 --- [nio-8180-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Dependent foreign key constraint violation in a referential integrity constraint. dbname =  'UkPaciudad', table name = 'caracteristica', constraint name = 'caracteris_2134295632'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución sería usar una anotación de Hibernate para que automáticamente realice el borrado en cascada, así cuando intentes borrar la entidad padre (Caracteristica), se borre la entidad hija (Produccion).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "caracteristica")
public class Caracteristica {

    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_produccion", nullable = true)
    @OnDelete( action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE ) // <-- Anotación
    Produccion produccion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione. Basicamente si una tabla que deseas eliminar tiene relaciones (FK) con otras tablas, no va a dejarte. Para ello hay que analizar las relaciones de la fila que se desea borrar y previamente borrar el child.